# Creating a couchbase clsuter via docker-compose, failing to create buckets and services (query service)

Tags: docker-compose, couchbase

Having some issues with this docker compose, trying to initialize a couchbase clusterafter starting it, the goal is to initialize this cluster and have the query service available, as well as to create the bucket from the start

this is the docker compose file I have:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSET_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  couchbase:
    image: couchbase:7.0.1
    container_name: couchbase
    ports:
      - "8091-8094:8091-8094"
      - "11207-11211:11207-11211"
    environment:
      COUCHBASE_SERVER_VERSION: 7.0.1
      COUCHBASE_USERNAME: admin
      COUCHBASE_PASSWORD: password
      COUCHBASE_BUCKET: broker-events
      COUCHBASE_BUCKET_RAMSIZE: 256
      COUCHBASE_ANALYTICS_MEMORY_QUOTA: 1024
      COUCHBASE_FEATURES: query
      COUCHBASE_INDEX_STORAGE_SETTING: memopt
      COUCHBASE_SERVICES: data,index,query
    volumes:
      - couchbase-data:/opt/couchbase/var

  couchbase-wait:
    image: alpine
    container_name: couchbase-wait
    depends_on:
      - couchbase
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c "apk add --no-cache curl && 
      until curl --silent --fail http://couchbase:8091 >/dev/null; do sleep 5; done;
      echo 'Couchbase cluster is now available';
      sleep 10;
      curl --silent --fail -u admin:password -X POST http://admin:password@couchbase:8091/pools/default -d memoryQuota=1024 -d indexMemoryQuota=256;
      echo 'Couchbase pool created';
      curl --silent --fail -u admin:password -X POST http://admin:password@couchbase:8091/pools/default/buckets -d name=broker-events -d bucketType=couchbase -d ramQuotaMB=256 -d authType=sasl -d saslPassword=;
      echo 'Couchbase bucket created';
      exit 0;"

volumes:
  couchbase-data:
```

So far everything is created, but no matter what I do, I am always greeted by this page when I go to localhost:8091
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPws9.png)

any tips will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure those environment variables are supported by the base Couchbase docker image? I suspect they are not, but I would be happy to be proven wrong (do you have a link to docs?) You may want to look into a custom docker image, like https://github.com/brantburnett/couchbasefakeit (I'm assuming you are using docker-compose for development purposes)

Comment: Hi, yes I am using this for development and demonstration purposes.